# Constraint for a column(1) that checks the values in another column(2) are equal to 'String1' and 'String2', setting column(1) to not null

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

How do you create a constraint for a column(1) that checks the values in another column(2)and is equal to  'String1' and 'String2' but not 'String3', therefore setting column(1) to not null
This is what I have tried so far

```
    Create Table ER(ERNo INTEGER,
ERSta Varchar2(8 CHAR) Default 'PENDING' Not Null,  
AUserNo Integer,
CONSTRAINT ERNoPK PRIMARY KEY(ERNO),
CONSTRAINT ERSta_check CHECK (ERSta IN ('PENDING', 'APPROVED', 'DENIED')),
CONSTRAINT AUserNoFK FOREIGN KEY (AUserNo) REFERENCES Users(UserNo),
CONSTRAINT AUserNo CHECK (WHEN (ERSta like('APPROVED')or ('DENIED')) THEN AUserNo not null);
```

So my question is: As AuserNo allows nulls already, How can I Set AUserNo to not null when either 'APPROVED' or 'DENIED' has been entered in ERSta?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check (ERSta NOT IN ('APPROVED', 'DENIED') or AUserNo is not null)
```

1. The check clause will be fulfilled if ERSta is another value than APPROVED/DENIED.
2. If ERSta is APPROVED or DENIED, then AUserNo must be not null.